# Need a regex that captures date & amount fields & ignore blank lines & other miscellaneous data

Tags: regex, google-sheets, regex-replace

**Goal:**

1. Capture **only** the purchase date, amount, and purchased item name(s).
2. Ignore all blank lines
3. Ignore Reference # & SHIPPING AND TAX string
4. Then, repeat this on the next grouping of purchases.

- I am using Google Sheets for this project.

**Sample data showing 3 purchases (ie blocks of data)**

**Note: spacing & SHIPPING AND TAX string varies inbetween**

```
01/12 P934200QXEHMBPNAD Acme MARKETPLACE SEATTLE WA $34.96    Date & Amount
                                                              Ignore (blank line)
                           435852496957                       Ignore
                           BOSCH CO2135 1/8 In. x 2-3/4 I     Purchased item name
                           BOSCH CO2131 1/16 In. x 1-7/8      Purchased item name
                           IZOD Men's Memory Foam Slipper     Purchased item name
                           SHIPPING AND TAX                   Ignore
                                                              Ignore (blank line)
01/12 P934200QXEHMB6MQ0 Acme MARKETPLACE SEATTLE WA $48.91
                           492577232349
                           LxTek Remanufactured Ink Cartr
                           SHEENGO Remanufactured Ink Car
02/02 P934200AEHMB7E12  Acme MARKETPLACE SEATTLE WA $21.60

                           659473773469
                           LHXEQR Tubing Adapter for ResM
                           SHIPPING AND TAX
```

**My updated attempt**

```
=index(if(len(C26:C33),REGEXREPLACE(C26:C33,"(?Ums)(\d{2}/\d{2}) .* (\$\d{1,}\.\d{1,2}).(?:^\s+\d+$)(.*)(?:\s+SHIPPING AND TAX)","$1,$2,$3"),))
```

**Unsuccessful results**

```
01/12 P934200QXEHMBPNAD Acme MARKETPLACE SEATTLE WA $34.96

#VALUE!
BOSCH CO2135 1/8 In. x 2-3/4 I
BOSCH CO2131 1/16 In. x 1-7/8
IZOD Men's Memory Foam Slipper
SHIPPING AND TAX

01/12 P934200QXEHMB6MQ0 Acme MARKETPLACE SEATTLE WA $48.91
#VALUE!
LxTek Remanufactured Ink Cartr
SHEENGO Remanufactured Ink Car
02/02 P934200DJEHMB7E12 AMAZON MARKETPLACE SEATTLE WA $21.60

#VALUE!
LHXEQR Tubing Adapter for ResM
SHIPPING AND TAX
```

```
Unsuccessful
- it did not ignore:
data btwn date & amount
blank lines
SHIPPING AND TAX
- Value issue - not handling Reference # well
Function REGEXREPLACE parameter 1 expects text values. But '435848996957' is a number and cannot be coerced to a text.
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Doing this in google sheets.  C&P thes data into cells, then hope to run Reyes’s on that cell range

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet or screenshot showcasing how the said data is arranged in cells and expected output (manually entered)

Comment: @rockinfreakshow - Agreed!  I just revamped the post.  I hope it is better. Look forward to your advice on the regex

Comment: As per the [ask], please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Bohemian - Ah, thank you for that.  Apologies, still learning.  I've removed the do nots and will replace using 3 backticks surrounding manual entries..  I believe that should be ok.

Comment: So `#VALUE!` may appear instead of the big number, and the intervening blank line is optional?

Comment: I'm stumped on the value error.  I thought it may be about proper format for that particular Gsheets cell.  So I changed it from Number> automatic to plain text.  but same error.  As for blank lines, none are optional & all should be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This matches one "block" (note: turn DOTALL flag on):

```
(\d\d\/\d\d).*(\$[\d.]+).(?:^\s+\d+$)(.*)SHIPPING AND TAX\n\n
```

Capturing:

- the date as group 1
- the amount as group 2
- the product lines as group 3

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/mUL6jYMow8XWUh).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it out & it works well on one block, but stumbles on larger data set.  Also, I took ur regex and mod'd it w/out losing your approach, and my stumbled too.  Well, i just re-vamped my post to make it more organized.  Look forward to your advice on the regex